# Regex to capture digits in a list enclosed in other characters

Tags: regex, python-3.x

**Hey,**

So, I have the following string (I removed a lot of numbers, since we don't need them) :

EDIT : see below

```
text = """
<--
first+second=?

first:
146,399,163,403,170,379,147,394,146,399

second:
156,141,136,156,136

-->"""
```

I'm trying to find a way to capture every numbers from first in a list, and from second in another list (using python, re.findall()).
So my goal is for python to return a list like that (for the "first" list enclosed between "first:" and "second:" :

```
[146, 399, 163, 403,170,379,147,394,146,399]
```

Unfortunately, I do not manage to create a regex to capture a group of digits enclosed in comma/newline, themselves being enclosed in first and second (or other). When doing so, I only manage to capture the first or last group of digits within the boundary I used.

Here's one of the incorrect expressions I used. I have tried many others and played with quantifiers on the capturing group and other stuff, but I just don't seem to be able to get it right.

```
first:.+(\d{2,3}).+second:
```

I know it would be way easier to capture the full list first and split it, but I would like to understand regex better, hence my persistance on it.

---

EDIT : Sorry... I should have added more of the initial strings, I shortened it too much. The thing is, the list goes on several lines, like so (still shortened, though) :

```
text = """
<!--
first:
146,399,163,403,170,393,169,391,166,386,170,381,170,371,170,355,169,346,167,335,170,329,170,320,170,
310,171,301,173,290,178,289,182,287,188,286,190,286,192,291,194,296,195,305,194,307,191,312,190,316,
332,155,348,156,353,153,366,149,379,147,394,146,399

second:
156,141,165,135,169,131,176,130,187,134,191,140,191,146,186,150,179,155,175,157,168,157,163,157,159,
77,155,81,148,87,140,96,138,105,141,110,136,111,126,113,129,118,117,128,114,137,115,146,114,155,115,
158,121,157,128,156,134,157,136,156,136
-->
""""
```

Comment: Your programing language?

Comment: I'm using python 3.5

Comment: Use the button **{}** after selecting your code to format code. Do not use a cite-environment for that. I dont see _ANY_ stringg in your question. python strings look like `myNumbers = '1,2,3,4'` or  `myOtherNumbers = "11,12,13,14"`

Comment: For regex, give us your EXACT (maybe shortened) data - else we can not fit the regex.

Comment: Sorry, string is indeed incorrect. I was referring to what was enclosing what I wishes to capture in a list, that is to say "first:" and "second:". The whole code block is indeed the string I'm operating on. The list in of numbers is much longer, and there is more text before and after both lists. I will add it if you think it to be relevant.

Comment: Yes, although there's more text before and after, but nothing fitting the expression to capture the digits. I'll edit.

Comment: You can't do it with a single `re` pattern, but if you may use PyPi regex module, you can. BTW, is `second:` *obligatory*? Should the list of numbers after `first:` be returned even if there is no `second:` after?

Comment: Ok, thank you :). I need `second:` as a limit for the first list. If there is no second `second:` list, yep, I'd rather want it to return the `first:` anyway. But I don't have a general application for this regex, I'm just using this piece of text to better understand regex (it actually comes from the PythonChallenge website).

Comment: They were all quite helpful. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cheat:

```
text = """
<--
first+second=?

first:
146,399,163,403,170,379,147,394,146,399

second:
156,141,136,156,136

-->"""

import re

first = list(map(int,re.findall(r"\d+",text[text.find("first:"):text.find("second:")])))
second = list(map(int,re.findall(r"\d+",text[text.find("second:"):])))

print(first)
print(second)
print(first+second)
```

Output:

```
[146, 399, 163, 403, 170, 379, 147, 394, 146, 399]
[156, 141, 136, 156, 136]
[146, 399, 163, 403, 170, 379, 147, 394, 146, 399, 156, 141, 136, 156, 136]
```

The cheat is:

- you only feed parts of your `text` to regex that you want to have
- you slice `text` so that it only uses the text between `'first:'` and `'second:'`
- then you slice it to use all after `'second:'`

to give you seperate lists. Then you add them together.

The `list(map(int, <regex_cmd> ))` is just so they come out as integers, not strings.

---

If you simply need all ints from your text, this would work as well:

```
def isInt(t):
    try:
        return int(t)
    except:
        pass


splitted = [int(l) for k in text.split("\n") 
            for p in k.split(" ") 
            for l in p.split(",") if isInt(l) is not None]

print(splitted)
```

Output:

```
[146, 399, 163, 403, 170, 379, 147, 394, 146, 399, 156, 141, 136, 156, 136]
```

Comment: Your might consider using `ast.literal_eval()` instead of writing your own function :)

Comment: Thank you. Between using map and a list completion like that : `[int(x) for x in re.findall(r"\d+", text[text.find("first:"):text.find("second:")])]`, what is the most efficient and Pythonic way ?

Comment: @Naboochodonosor list comp looks easier, map is more special ;) choose whichever you are more comfortable with. map generally has the advantage of providing a generator, but in your case you are immediately consuming the map result into a list so me thinks it does not matter

Answer (score 4):

**Note -** As of this edit, there are a few answers from much more knowledgeable users, but so far, this seems to be the only one with one line of code to answer your question.

You could try this statement:

```
x = re.findall(r'(\w+?):\s+((?:\d+,?)+)', text)
```

Which returns the following array when `x` is printed:

```
[('first', '146,399,163,403,170,379,147,394,146,399'), ('second', '156,141,136,156,136')]
```

## Explanation -

This regex not only finds first and second like your question states but if at any point of time your code contains, say:

```
third:
123, 124, 12, 1
```

Or something of the sort, the regex would even match that.

`x` returns an array with two tuples - each one has the first element as the name i.e. `first`, `second` and so on, while each second element is the actual string of numbers.

The `r` at the start of the regex string indicates that it is a raw string, essentially forgoing those pesky double-backslashes.
`(\w+?)` is the group 1 which matches the text before the numbers like `first`, `second` and even other text should your sample input contain it.
`:` indicates that the text like first or second will be followed by a colon,
`\s+` matches one or more spaces (in this case, even newlines)
`((?:\d+,?)+)` is the second group which contains the actual string of digits
`(?:\d+,?)` is a non-capturing group which tells the regex to match one-or-more digits (which may be followed by a comma), and the `+` after the non-capturing group means that this sequence will be repeated one-or-more times.

---

**Oh, and one more thing -**

To access the desired matches - be it the label `first`, `second`, etc. or their respective digits, you can use this:

```
for match in x:
    print(match[0])
    print(match[1])
    print()
```

Essentially, the `match` is the tuple containing the label at `[0]` and the digits at `[1]`

---

**Edit 1 -**

To capture the multiple lines of numbers as you have recently specified, you can simply add a `\n?` to your regex like so:

```
x = re.findall(r'(\w+?):\s+((?:\d+,?\n?)+)', text)
```

Which matches an optional space alongside. However, there is a catch: When printed, `match[1]` looks like:

```
146,399,163,403,170,393,169,391,166,386,170,381,170,371,170,355,169,346,167,335,170,329,170,320,170,
310,171,301,173,290,178,289,182,287,188,286,190,286,192,291,194,296,195,305,194,307,191,312,190,316,
332,155,348,156,353,153,366,149,379,147,394,146,399,1111
```

But `match` itself looks like:

`('first', '146,399,163,403,170,393,169,391,166,386,170,381,170,371,170,355,169,346,167,335,170,329,170,320,170,\n310,171,301,173,290,178,289,182,287,188,286,190,286,192,291,194,296,195,305,194,307,191,312,190,316,\n332,155,348,156,353,153,366,149,379,147,394,146,399,1111\n')`

For the first element of `x`.

Do note the presence of the physical `\n`s in the match, which **will interfere in any arithmetic calculations you want to do.**

Comment: I like it - postprocessing to ints can happen later. Closer then my try at it ;)  +1

Comment: Thanks !. So, I did a mistake while shortening the text I'm using : the list goes on several lines. To solve that, I changed the`,?` of your last non capturing group in `(?:,?|,\n)` but it still only captures the first line, and I don't see what I've missed. I don't need to repeat the expression `,\n`, since the `,?` is there for the end of the list. Also, `\s`doesn't work either.

Comment: @Naboochodonosor No worries, I've updated my answer accordingly, but the new regex **will also capture the \n of the enter key**, so performing any arithmetic operation will be tricky.

Comment: @Naboochodonosor Hopefully, you won't need to :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a two-step approach:

1. Get the items via a regular expression using a dict comprehension
2. Convert the obtained string via `ast.literal_eval()` to a list

---

The regular expression could be:

```
^                         # start of the line
(?P<group>[a-z]+):[\n\r]  # a group named "group" with lowercase letters, 
                          # followed by a colon
(?P<lst>(?:\d+,?\s*)+)    # digits, commas and spaces
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/cHjI7T/1).

---

In `Python`:

```
import re
from ast import literal_eval

rx = re.compile(r'''
    ^
    (?P<group>[a-z]+):[\n\r]
    (?P<lst>(?:\d+,?\s*)+)
    ''', re.M | re.X)

result = {m.group('group'): literal_eval('[{}]'.format(m.group('lst'))) 
          for m in rx.finditer(text)}
print(result)
```

Which yields a dict:

```
{'first': [146, 399, 163, 403, 170, 393, 169, 391, 166, 386, 170, 381, 170, 371, 170, 355, 169, 346, 167, 335, 170, 329, 170, 320, 170, 310, 171, 301, 173, 290, 178, 289, 182, 287, 188, 286, 190, 286, 192, 291, 194, 296, 195, 305, 194, 307, 191, 312, 190, 316, 332, 155, 348, 156, 353, 153, 366, 149, 379, 147, 394, 146, 399], 
 'second': [156, 141, 165, 135, 169, 131, 176, 130, 187, 134, 191, 140, 191, 146, 186, 150, 179, 155, 175, 157, 168, 157, 163, 157, 159, 77, 155, 81, 148, 87, 140, 96, 138, 105, 141, 110, 136, 111, 126, 113, 129, 118, 117, 128, 114, 137, 115, 146, 114, 155, 115, 158, 121, 157, 128, 156, 134, 157, 136, 156, 136]}
```

Afterwards, you can access your items via i.e. `result['first']`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with separate passes for the first and second groups, then this will do it:

First group: `(?<=first:.+)(\d{2,3})(?=.+second:)`

Second group: `(?<=second:.+)(\d{2,3})`

These use lookahead and lookbehind patterns to check the position of "first:" and "second:" labels relative to the numbers being matched.

Comment: Thank you :) . However, it returns an error, as the lookbehind seems to require a fixed length, which would forbid the use of an non exact quantifier.